# Celluloid callback

Tags: ruby, callback, celluloid

How can I get notified when an async method has finished it's job (callback) when using Celluloid?

Sample code:

```
  require 'celluloid/autostart'

  class Test
    include Celluloid

    def initialize(aaa)
      @aaa = aaa
    end

    def foo
      sleep 20
      @bbb = 'asdasd'
    end

    def bar
      "aaa is: #{@aaa}, bbb is: #{@bbb}"
    end
  end
  x = Test.new 111
  x.async.foo
```

I would like to get notified as soon as the job inside foo is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the Observer pattern. Celluloid supports this via Notifications. Take a look at the wiki for some information:  https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid/wiki/Notifications

Here's a working code example:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'celluloid/autostart'

class Test
  include Celluloid
  include Celluloid::Notifications

  def initialize(aaa)
    @aaa = aaa
  end

  def foo
    sleep 2
    @bbb = 'asdasd'
    publish "done!", "Slept for 2 seconds and set @bbb = #{@bbb}"
  end

  def bar
    "aaa is: #{@aaa}, bbb is: #{@bbb}"
  end
end

class Observer
  include Celluloid
  include Celluloid::Notifications

  def initialize
    subscribe "done!", :on_completion
  end

  def on_completion(*args)
    puts "finished, returned #{args.inspect}"
  end
end


y = Observer.new
x = Test.new 111
x.async.foo

sleep 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now I think the new Conditions feature is the preferred way to handle this.

The example from the [Celluloid wiki page on Conditions](https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid/wiki/Conditions) is too large to paste here, but simply put you can create a Condition object that is signalled by the called method once it is done. The caller can simply wait until the condition is met.

Comment: I think TS asked of async callback execution which differs from *wating* for async return